# Converting CSV data format

Tags: excel, csv, batch-file, accumulate

First time question here..

I have 100's of CSV files I need to convert using whatever means you think necessary.

The format is an ever-accumulating value e.g.

```
01/01/2012,96,1000,1100,1150,1200,1400,1450,......
02/01/2012,96,1900,2050,2060,......
```

But I need this in a single value format, so I need the difference between each value e.g.

```
01/01/2012,96,100,50,50,200,50......
02/01/2012,96,150,10,......
```

96 is the no. of values in each row.

Thats the 1st part, the next is to ignore any row which doesn't have 96 values,
so:

```
01/01/2012,1024,96,96.7,96.5,96.3,.....
```

would be ignored.

I'm very new to writing scripts/macros so baby steps please!

Comment: Will all wanted lines have Integers only? (as your "to-be-ignored" line has non-integers)

Comment: The one with non-integers is descending in value too.

Comment: yes - but `set /a` will not work with non-integers

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED. I suggest:
Import a .csv to Excel.
Turn on Macro recorder.
Text to Columns with `,` as delimiter.
Filter column containing `96` to select any value other than `96` and delete those rows.
Add a row for the differences.
Concatenate the results of `96` columns with the likes of `=A2&","&B2&","….`
Adjust code to suit.